# [WCF]configure a Port with an SSL certificate with Httpcfg.exe

Tags: ssl, certificate

I tried to configure a Port with an SSL certificate, this could be achieved by Httpcfg.ext tool, but I failed to find in my windows 10, I try to download it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18546, but it only supports Windows XP, could you share us how to use Httpcfg.exe in Windows 10?

Answer (score 3):

HttpCfg.exe is not available for Windows 10. You may want to check out [Configuring HTTP and HTTPS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN. It states that `httpcfg` is used on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, whereas you should use `netsh` for pretty much any Windows operating system from Vista on.

If you are looking to do this programmatically then you could investigate using the [HTTP Server API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364510(v=vs.85).aspx).